# Syntax error in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql

I did this simple SQL Query succesfuly from PHP Admin 4 years ago with SQL 5.1. Now I try the same in SQL 5.5 for my new project and getting a syntax error. Mayby somebody can help me to get in the game again.Thanks

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `mfl` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`rank` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) TYPE = MYISAM
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE = MYISAM' at line 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

`Engine=MyISAM`

as Type is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but Engine=MyISAM doesnt work either. Now I'm getting
#1046 - No database selected

Comment: Engine=MyISAM is correct but spaces were missing so the final syntax is this 
Engine = MyISAM